# SpringBoot Application Log Files in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a SpringBoot application that I deployed onto AWS for learning purposes. My application exposes REST API and I am trying to understand how to view the application logs in AWS.

This is how my SpringBoot application's GET API is configured.

```
   @GetMapping
    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        logger.info("Reached All GetMapping on the server");
        return service.getMovies();
    }
```

I deployed the service onto Elastic BeanStalk. I then went to logs folder in Elastic Beanstalk > Environments > my_application_name > logs. I am seeing a zip to download that contains the log statements:

```
Dec 23 19:22:18 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:18.471  INFO 4108 --- [           main] i.f.r.restapiaws.RestapiawsApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Dec 23 19:22:21 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:21.227  INFO 4108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
Dec 23 19:22:21 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:21.254  INFO 4108 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
Dec 23 19:22:21 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:21.258  INFO 4108 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
Dec 23 19:22:21 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:21.379  INFO 4108 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Dec 23 19:22:21 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:21.381  INFO 4108 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2638 ms
Dec 23 19:22:22 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:22.616  INFO 4108 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
Dec 23 19:22:22 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:22.851  INFO 4108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
Dec 23 19:22:22 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:22.874  INFO 4108 --- [           main] i.f.r.restapiaws.RestapiawsApplication   : Started RestapiawsApplication in 5.999 seconds (JVM running for 8.107)
Dec 23 19:22:34 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:34.919  INFO 4108 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Dec 23 19:22:34 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:34.920  INFO 4108 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Dec 23 19:22:34 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:22:34.922  INFO 4108 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Dec 23 19:25:06 ip-172-31-42-142 web: 2021-12-23 19:25:06.425  INFO 4108 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] i.f.r.r.controllers.RestAPIController    : Reached All GetMapping on the server
```

Is this how the logs appear in practical AWS implementations?. I was under the impressions that CloudWatch can give this provision by default without having to download the logs as a zip and extract them to do analysis. In a practical implementation with thousands of requests it does not appear accurate that the only option is to download these log files as a zip and then extract them.

I'm new to AWS and so if there is a configuration/connection that I am missing, please suggest.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk does not stream logs to CloudWatch by default, but this can be enabled when we create an application. In order to do this, we have to select `Configure More Options` and then in the `Software` section select `Edit`:

[image]

From there we can enable log streaming:

[image]

If we already have an application with an environment, we can still enable streaming to CloudWatch by going into `Configurations` and than `Software` section:

[image]